# Deferred Deep Linking in iOS 11

Tags: ios, deep-linking

Before iOS 11 we used cookie based solution for Deferred Deep Linking. According to the [Branch.io's article](https://blog.branch.io/wwdc-2017-whats-coming-in-ios-11-for-deep-linking-and-app-discovery/) in iOS 11 it is not possible.

So, how to handle Deferred Deep Linking in iOS 11? Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Guaranteed matches

Branch actually leverages its network of previously made browser-to-device matches to make a 100% accurate deep links. If a user has been matched by one of Branch's other apps in the past, that user can be identified by their IDFA any time they click a link again in the future. This is why it makes deep linking so hard to build by yourself.

### Not guaranteed matches

If a user has not been identified in the past, Branch will then perform a fingerprinting technique that involves generating a fingerprint using the os, screen size, IP, etc when a user clicks a link and matching it to another fingerprint that is generated by the same parameters when the user opens the app.

Answer (score 2):

There is no guaranteed single way to do this anymore. Branch accomplishes this the same way they did before the shared cookies were introduced in iOS 11 which is by trying to match users using a few identifiers such as user agent and IP address, but even they acknowledge that they can't match with 100% accuracy by giving you a `match_guaranteed` flag to let you know if the SDK did not identify the user with certainty.